# rust generic type with trait bound when use trait objects

Tags: rust, trait-objects

```
trait MyTrait {
    fn my_f(&self) ;
}

struct A {}
struct B {}

impl MyTrait for A {
    fn my_f(&self) {
        println!("A.my_f()");
    }
}
impl MyTrait for B {
    fn my_f(&self) {
        println!("B.my_f()");
    }
}

struct MyList<T: MyTrait> {
    list: Vec<T>
}

fn main() {
    let list = MyList {
        list: vec![
            Box::new(A{}),
            Box::new(B{})
        ]
    };
}
```

I followed this article, [Using Trait Objects That Allow for Values of Different Types](https://rustwiki.org/en/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html)

According to this article:

> This restricts us to a Screen instance that has a list of components all of type Button or all of type TextField. If you’ll only ever have homogeneous collections, using generics and trait bounds is preferable because the definitions will be monomorphized at compile time to use the concrete types.
>
> On the other hand, with the method using trait objects, one Screen instance can hold a Vec that contains a Box as well as a Box. Let’s look at how this works, and then we’ll talk about the runtime performance implications.

But this code can't be compiled.

Comment: Your `MyList` shouldn't be generic over `T`. Instead it should hold trait objects (i.e. some kind of reference to `dyn MyTrait`), e.g.: `list: Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait>>` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cc3dd5869ccd10f0f7b3195f846d9de6)).

Comment: Yes, I know `list: Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait>>` will work, but rust document suggests this will work, how to handle it ?
```
pub struct Screen<T: Draw> {
    pub components: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T> Screen<T>
where
    T: Draw,
{
    pub fn run(&self) {
        for component in self.components.iter() {
            component.draw();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read more closely the section on [Defining a Trait for Common Behavior](https://rustwiki.org/en/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html#defining-a-trait-for-common-behavior). It defines `Screen` in listing 17-4 with a `Vec<Box<dyn Draw>>`:

```
pub struct Screen {
    pub components: Vec<Box<dyn Draw>>,
}
```

Then it says:

> we ***could*** have defined the `Screen` struct using a generic type and a trait bound as in Listing 17-6

Emphasis on the conditional "could". It then goes on to explain why using a generic type and trait bound doesn't work:

> This *(1)* restricts us to a `Screen` instance that has a list of components all of type `Button` or all of type `TextField`.
>
> […]
>
> On the other hand, with the method using trait objects *(2)*, one `Screen` instance can hold a `Vec<T>` that contains a `Box<Button>` as well as a `Box<TextField>`.

(1) using a generic type and trait bound

(2) i.e. with `Box<dyn<Draw>>`

Comment: Oh, I've struggled for almost 2 hours... OK I see, sorry, I misunderstood. Thank you.

Comment: If you feel that the documentation is unclear and could be improved, don't hesitate to [open an issue on Github](https://github.com/rust-lang/book/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md).